# What is the subtraction (-) operator is used for in JavaScript other than math?

Tags: javascript

Im having a hard time to understand the use of (-) operator in JS for non math proposes.
I have the following code :

```
let jeff = (new URL(location).searchParams.get('jeff') || "No parameters.");
eval(`ma = "Ma name ${jeff}"`);
document.write(ma)
```

And the Following URL :

```
basic.html?jeff=%22-alert(1)-%22
```

Im having a hard time to understand how the alert is being raised.
Appreciate the help.

I was expecting to get a string printed and not the execution of alert function.

Comment: `-` operator is subtraction and nothing else, as there is no operator overloading in Javascript (yet). The `-` you see is NOT an operator, it is a string. Do `decodeURI("basic.html?jeff=%22-alert(1)-%22")` and you will get: `'basic.html?jeff="-alert(1)-"'`. So it is part of the URL parameter `jeff`, probably to be used to execute javascript later down the line.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, Actually i tried other operators like plus (+), and only with (-) it executes the alert function.
So for :
`basic.html?jeff="+alert(1)+"`
The JS wont execute the alert function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the subtraction operator `-` used for in JavaScript, other than math?

This is a strange question, but it’s not the *real* question you’re asking here.

> I’m having a hard time to understand how the alert is being raised.

*This* is the actual concern.

If you don’t understand how a process like this works, it helps to go through it step by step.

Look at the first line:

```js
let jeff = (new URL(location).searchParams.get("jeff") || "No parameters.");
```

The [`URL`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL) constructor stringifies its first argument and parses it as a URL.
[`location`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/location) is the object that holds information about the current page’s URL.
It’s stringified as the full URL.
The `searchParams` property is a [`URLSearchParams`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object, which holds all the query parameters of the URL, such as `?jeff=%22-alert(1)-%22`, in a structured, decoded way.
[`.get("jeff")`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get) attempts to get the value of the `jeff` parameter.

Note that [URLs are subject to encoding](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL).
`%22` is the [percent encoding](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) of the quote character `"`; `%2B` is the percent encoding of the plus character `+`; `+` is the URL encoding of a single space  ; and so on.

The `|| "No parameters."` [defaults to the string `"No parameters."`](/q/6439579/4642212) if the `jeff` parameter is empty or not present.
If your location is `https://example.com/?jeff=%22-alert(1)-%22` The result, which is assigned to the variable `jeff`, is `'"-alert(1)-"'`.

Second line:

```js
eval(`ma = "Ma name ${jeff}"`);
```

`` `ma = "Ma name ${jeff}"` `` is a [template literal](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which interpolates the variable `jeff` into the rest of the string; the resulting string is `'ma = "Ma name "-alert(1)-""'`.
[`eval`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) executes strings as code.
So, effectively, this line says: `ma = "Ma name "-alert(1)-""` (or somewhat cleaner: `ma = "Ma name " - alert(1) - "";`).

This [subtracts](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Subtraction) `alert(1)` from `"Ma name "`, and then subtracts `""` from that intermediate result.
In order to evaluate this, `alert(1)` is executed.
**That’s how the `alert` window appears.**
Both the intermediate and the final result are [`NaN`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN), because they involve the return value from the `alert`, namely `undefined`.
`NaN` is then assigned to the variable `ma`.

Third line:

```js
document.write(ma)
```

This just [writes](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/write) the resulting `NaN` (as the string `"NaN"`) into the open document stream (or, if closed, opens a new one, *then* writes into it).

---

Run this snippet to examine the intermediate results.
Note that the `eval` and the reference to the real `location` have been removed in the snippet; this is just to give you a general idea of how intermediate results might be examined.

```js
const locationHref = "https://example.com/?jeff=%22-alert(1)-%22",
  urlObject = new URL(locationHref),
  searchParams = urlObject.searchParams,
  jeffParameter = searchParams.get("jeff"),
  jeff = jeffParameter || "No parameters.",
  jeffIfNotFound = null || "No parameters.",
  interpolatedString = `ma = "Ma name ${jeff}"`;

console.log({
  locationHref,
  urlObject,
  searchParams, // Look at this in your browser console; the Stack Snippet doesn’t show a very useful representation.
  jeffParameter,
  jeff,
  jeffIfNotFound,
  interpolatedString
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

---

Back to your first question:

> What is the subtraction operator `-` used for in JavaScript, other than math?

There is nothing special about `-` in this code.
Try any of the operators in this query string: `?jeff=%22**alert(1)/alert(1)*alert(1)>>>~alert(1)^alert(1)===alert(1)||!alert(1)<%22`, and many more; this’ll alert six times with the meaningless result `1`.

[The Subtraction Operator](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-subtraction-operator-minus) is only used for math.
Any other application is either a [hack](/q/13341698/4642212) or meaningless.

> Actually, I tried other operators like plus (`+`)

But you didn’t URL-encode it correctly.

```js
new URLSearchParams("jeff=a+b").get("jeff"); // Result: "a b".
new URLSearchParams("jeff=a%2Bb").get("jeff"); // Result: "a+b".
new URLSearchParams("jeff=a%2Bb%25c%26%26d").get("jeff"); // Result: "a+b%c&&d".
```

The `+` works just the same way.
The important thing is that functions will *execute* in order to be *evaluated*.
If they’re somewhere in the middle of operators, then they’re the operands which will be evaluated; it doesn’t matter *which* operators are used (unless they’re [short-circuiting](/q/12554578/4642212), in which case evaluation may be skipped).